# Counting digit in column based on subject

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am just using formulas in excel and was wondering how you could count all the 0s until a 1 is reached, and then start the process over again, based on subject number. If this is not possible simply with formulas, how could I write a VBA code for this?

Right now I am trying to use,

```
=IF(OR(F4=0,F3=1),"",COUNTIFS($A$2:A2, $A$2,$F$2:F2,0)-SUM($I$2:I2))
```

which I input in I3 and I change the `COUNTIFS($A$#:A#, $A$#...)` part for each subject number.

This seems to work with the exception of the last grouping, as it won't output a number before the next subject.

Example Data:

```
subid         yes       number_yes(output)
1             0
1             0
1             0            3
1             1
1             0            1
1             1
1             0
2             0
2             0            2
2             1
2             0
2             0
3             
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

A blank cell is numerically zero and that is one of your accepted conditions. Differentiate between blanks and zero values.

```
=IF(and(f4<>"", OR(F4=0,F3=1)),"",COUNTIFS($A$2:A2, $A$2,$F$2:F2,0)-SUM($I$2:I2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jeeped answer. If you use `-SUMIF($A$2:A2,A3,$I$2:I2)` instead of `-SUM($I$2:I2)` you don't need to adjust this part for each subject number. Just use the following formula in I3 and copy it down.

```
=IF(AND(F4<>"",OR(F4=0,F3=1)),"",COUNTIFS($A$2:A3,A3,$F$2:F3,0)-SUMIF($A$2:A2,A3,$I$2:I2))
```

Note that I also changed the second parameter in the `COUNTIFS` to `A3`.